# How to call a function from HTML page on every for loop using *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am fetching data from an API in a array using below code in my `page.ts`

```
this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {
      this.list = data;
```

On my `page.html`, I am showing data using `*ngFor` , code shown below:

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayList;let i=index;" >
    <ion-item>{{list.TASKDESC}}{{list.ENTUSR }}{{list.DEADLINE_DT }}</ion-item>
```

In every for loop, I want to call a function `checkdeadline_dt()` and print in console `list.DEADLINE_DT`.

Please advise code on HTML/TS page as how to achieve this.

Comment: why do you need it to be called in your `*ngFor` and not inside your subscribe function already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayList;let i=index;" (click)="checkdeadline_dt(list.DEADLINE_DT)">
<ion-item>{{list.TASKDESC}}{{list.ENTUSR }}{{list.DEADLINE_DT }}</ion-item>
```